# elif not behaving as expected - beginner/ noob problems

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a half dozen if and elif statements and the second elif won't work. It has something to do with the less than sign because the greater than sign works Why?

```
elif temperature < 10:
   print("Don't bother getting out of bed")
```

Complete source:

```
temperature = 3

if temperature > 30:
    print("Its a hot day, drink plenty of water")
if temperature < 15:
    print("No need to drink any water today")
elif temperature > 39:
    print("Its really hot so stay indoors")
elif temperature < 10:
    print("Don't bother getting out of bed")
else:
    print("Its a lovely day today")

# this returns:
# No need to drink any water today
# Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I've added the rest of the code so it's more obvious. The problem is that your first `if` already matches. Since 10 is less than 15, it will never reach the `elif temperature < 10`

Comment: *All* the later cases are already covered by earlier cases – e.g. for a temperature to be bigger than 39 it has to be bigger than 30 as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's because a statement like this:

```
if condition_a:
    pass  # body 1
elif condition_b:
    pass  # body 2
```

is equivalent to

```
if condition_a:
    pass  # body 1
else:
    if condition_b:
        pass  # body 2
```

or

```
if condition_a:
    pass  # body 1
if not condition_a and condition_b:
    pass  # body 2
```

Look at how your code looks if I transform it to the third form:

```
if temperature < 15:
    print("No need to drink any water today")
if temperature >= 15 and temperature > 39:
    print("Its really hot so stay indoors")
if temperature >= 15 and temperature <= 39 and temperature < 10:
    print("Don't bother getting out of bed")
if temperature >= 15 and temperature <= 39 and temperature >= 10:
    print("Its a lovely day today")
```

I hope you can see that `temperature >= 15 and temperature < 10` will never be `True`.

To solve this, you should always order your `if`/`elif` suites such that the most specific cases gets checked first.